# Axios request automatically set url

Tags: reactjs, api, express, axios

I'm trying to implement a function that upload image using Express.js as the api server and React.js in the client.

In the api server, I've defined an uploading image route like:

`userRoute.js`

```
module.exports = app => {
    const User = require("../controllers/userController")
    let router = require("express").Router()
    const authJWT = require("../middleware/authJWT")
    const upload = require("../utils/multer")
   
    // endpoint is http://localhost:8800/api/users/profilePicture
    router.post(
        "/profilePicture",
        upload.single("image"),
        authJWT,
        User.uploadProfilePicture
    )

   // some other routes

    app.use("/api/users", router)
}
```

In client, I used Axios to handle requests

`agent.ts`

```
// the axios instance with the api endpoint 
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8800/api",
})

// app user-related requests 
const AppUser = {
   // I use this to upload image to api server
    uploadProfilePicture: (image: Blob) => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("image", image)
        return axios.post<Image>("profilePicture", formData, {
                headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
        })
    },

    // other requests ...
}
```

When I click on the upload file button and check the inspect console, the upload file url was `http://localhost:3001/profiles/profilePicture`, which is not the server url, and of course this route is not the same as the route I defined in the server API `http://localhost:8000/users/profilePicture`. So it returned 404 not found.

Comment: you have to use `axiosInstance.post`

Comment: @Mani Opps! I forgot it. Thank you for the reminder!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reminder of @Mani, in `agent.ts` I defined Axios as *not* default instance. However in the request, I used it as the default instance, so it didn't work.

I changed

```
return axios.post<Image>("profilePicture", formData, {
                headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
 })
```

to

```
return axiosInstance.post<Image>("profilePicture", formData, {
                headers: { "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
       })
```

So it works again.